# Linking a search form to a specific URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, search

I'm trying to achieve the following:

When a user enters a 5 digit ID in the form at `www.something.com`, the user would be redirected to `www.something.com/obtain/(5 digit ID)`.

I know manually entering the url `www.something.com/obtain/(5 digit ID)` would trigger the desired action but how do I create a form that does that instead?

Is there anyway that I can achieve this with `<%= form_tag .... %>` ?

Rake routes has the following entry

> obtain        /obtain/:pid(.:format)       products#obtain
>   {:id=>/\d+/}

Currently in the controller

```
  def obtain
    scrapy = Scraper.new

    @product = scrapy.scrape((params[:pid]))

    if @product
      redirect_to @product, notice: 'Product successfully updated'
    elsif
      redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Invalid product requested'
    end
  end
```

Comment: change your elsif to a else. Would be more 'correct'.

Answer (score 0):

If you are submitting a form, you will have a function or some code to process the inputs, ie: at least extracting the request.query's like:

```
$var = request.query("ID")
```

So after that code has performed it's tasks/s all you need is a line for a redirection like:

```
whatever.redirect("www.something.com/obtain/" & $var
```

Answer (score 0):

In your view create a form:

```
<%= form_tag({:controller=>"products", :action=>"obtain"}, :method => "get") do %>
        <%= text_field_tag(:pid) %>
        <%= submit_tag "Search with PID" %>
<% end %>
```

I don't know if your `obtain` action is triggered with a `get`, but if its not just change it to whatever it is triggered (post, put).

Comment: Obtain doesn't actually search for a specific pid in the database. It actually passes it to another function to carry out some other function. I'm not sure what I should modify here.

Comment: oh i see you added it. I also modified the answer. Is this good or am i missing something?

Comment: This doesn't work for what I'm trying to do. I want the form to pass the ID to products#obtain and let obtain perform what's necessary. `@product = Product.find_by_pid(params[:pid])` will probably fail because obtain will actually be creating a new product. Nvm, just saw that it actually updated, still checking it out.

Comment: Edited again to make it more DRY. I think this should work if the `obtain` action works

Comment: Oh my god, wait a second, please i will edited, there is no need to make a extra action for this. Check it out in a minute.

Comment: That's actually what I'm looking for but I'm still getting an error.. No route matches {:controller=>"products", :action=>"obtain"}

Comment: What is the http method you are using? Change the `:method` part if you are using something else than `get`

Comment: I don't think that's the issue. I'm getting that error when I'm trying to load up the `index page` that is rendering the partial that has the code above.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26312/discussion-between-zippie-and-user1043625)